# Azure Mobile Apps receiving webhooks

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, webhooks

I need to receive webhook requests in the same backend as my mobile app. They are sent as POST with content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. As far as I can tell, I have to use the [MobileAppController] attribute on my controllers, but this forces me to send in a header named "zumo-api-version" (which my webhook provider obviously does not send in the request). Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: you don't have to use the attribute on your controller. it just indicates that it is a mobile app controller. but you can use a regular `ApiController`

Comment: @woelliJ how would one go about this? Whenever I try to create a custom route for my webapi configuration it messes up azure's own default config

Answer (score 0):

> but this forces me to send in a header named "zumo-api-version" (which my webhook provider obviously does not send in the request).

You can opt out of version checking by setting a value of true for the app setting MS_SkipVersionCheck. Specify this either in your web.config or in the Application Settings section of the Azure portal. After setting MS_SkipVersionCheck to true, zumo-api-version header is not required.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MS_SkipVersionCheck" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Any updates? Have you tried my suggestions? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.